# How to select the device to install app to with the default ant build.xml generated by "android create project"?

Tags: android

I've run:

```
android create project \
    --target 1 \
    --name MyName \
    --path . \
    --activity MyActivity \
    --package com.cirosantilli.android_cheat
```

which generated a `build.xml`. But if I run:

```
adb debug install
```

with multiple devices available, it fails with:

```
[exec] error: more than one device/emulator
```

So how do I set the correct device?

I know that with `adb` I would need `-s`:

```
adb devices -l
adb -s emulator-5554 installd my.apk
```

and I also know where the generated `.apk` is located, but it would be cleaner if I could do it with the default `build.xml`, which already knows the location of the `.apk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass arguments to `adb` as:

```
ant -Dadb.device.arg='-s emulator-5554' installd
```